# slds-modal class not working inside Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

The typical modal code from [the lds reference website](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) does not work inside a community. There is no overlay behind the modal that covers the rest of the screen. Has anyone else encountered this and found a way to fix it that doesn’t involve having to write the css from scratch?

Comment: Have you used [`lightning:overlayLibrary`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary) base aura component? If not; then that would be recommended approach.

Comment: The modal includes a form where the submit button would be in the footer, which would need to access a value in the form which would be in the modal body.. Using this method seems like it would make all of this extremely messy.

Comment: And I;m assuming that would probably still use `<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open”>`? Which is what seems not to be working in communities for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I was missing `<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>` as a sibling of the modal `<section>` ‍♀️